# Get List of artifacts in an Ivy Repositoty

Tags: ivy, repository

I manage an Ivy repository with an extensive number of artifacts and i have been requested to list all third party librarys which we have a hundred odd. does anyone know of a a way to retrieve a list of artifacts from an ivy repo?

Comment: Sonatype Nexus™ Open Source Edition, Version: 1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found no such way to do this, i wrote a script in java to get the results, thought i might share the answer if people wanted it in the future, it is also formatted to be copied straight into an excel document.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class ListArtifacts {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Collection<File> all = new ArrayList<File>(); 
        addTree(new File("."), all);
        String delimeter = "\\.";
        List<String> remove = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> everything = new ArrayList<String>();
        remove.add("pom");
        remove.add("jar");
        remove.add("xml");
        remove.add("txt");
        remove.add("sha1");
        remove.add("md5");
        remove.add("metadata");
        remove.add("tar");
        remove.add("gz");
        remove.add("zip");
        remove.add("rar");


        FileWriter fWriter = null; 
        BufferedWriter writer = null; 
        try { 
            fWriter = new FileWriter("info.txt"); 
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter); 

            Iterator itr = all.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext() == true){
                String[] split;
                String temp = itr.next().toString();
                split = temp.split(delimeter);
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;
                boolean flag = false;
                while (i < split.length){
                    while (j < remove.size()){
                        if (split[i].equals(remove.get(j))){
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }       
                if (flag == false){
                    String output = "";
                    int k=0;
                    boolean flag2 = false;
                    boolean hasVersion = false;
                    while (k < split.length){
                        if (flag2 == true){
                            output += ".";
                            flag2 = false;
                        }                       
                        output = output + split[k].toString();

                        boolean lastInt = false;
                        try{
                        String last = split[k].substring(split[k].length() - 1); 
                        if (isInteger(last) == true)
                            lastInt = true;
                        }catch(Exception e){}

                        if ((isInteger(split[k].toString()) == true) || (lastInt == true)){
                            flag2 = true;
                            hasVersion = true;
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
                    if (hasVersion == true){
                        everything.add(output.substring(1));
                        writer.append(output.substring(1));
                        writer.newLine(); 
                    }
                }
            }
            int i = 0;
            String delim = "\\\\";
            String finalOutput = "";
            String toSplit = "";
            while (i < everything.size()){
                toSplit = everything.get(i);
                String[] split2 = toSplit.split(delim);
                finalOutput = split2[0] + "\t";
                int j = 1;
                while (j < split2.length-2){
                    finalOutput += split2[j] + ".";
                    j++;
                }
                finalOutput += split2[split2.length-2] + "\t";
                finalOutput += split2[split2.length-1];
                writer.append(finalOutput);
                writer.newLine(); 
                i++;
            }

            writer.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
        } 

        System.out.println(all); 
    } 

    public static boolean isInteger(String input )   
    {   
        try  
        {   
            Integer.parseInt(input);   
            return true;   
        }   
        catch(Exception e)   
        {   
            return false;   
        }   
    } 

    static void addTree(File file, Collection<File> all) { 
        File[] children = file.listFiles(); 
        if (children != null) { 
            for (File child : children) { 
                all.add(child); 
                addTree(child, all); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

im sure this can be done much more cleanly, but i did no higher thinking just did the first thing i thought of with no revision.

Comment: this is run on cmd line in the repository and generates the list of artifacts/versions to a txt document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this using ivy during a build, the [report](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/report.html) task should help you get a report of all the JARs you are using.

If you are trying to fetch these details from the repository manager (covering all possible users), could you answer the question from @oers? Repository managers often offer some API that you can use to get reports about the artifacts that they store.

Comment: build time reports are not so useful to me.